# reading from different files without keeping old content perl

Tags: perl, stdin, filereader, fileinputstream, filehandle

so i have a function which open a file to read from, analyse the lines and write some in a new file. I call this funktion several times with different files. But now i noticed, that by every new function call, the lines of the previous files get read in too. How can i prevent that?

content of es.txt:

`El
anarquismo
es
una
filosofía
política
y
social
que
llama`

content of dt.txt:

    `der
    Regel
    mit
    Veränderungen
    der
    chemischen
    Bindungen
    in`

after the program run, the created file ProfileDE looks like this (although it should only contain tokens from "dt.txt", some tokens are from "es.txt"):

```
una
ilos
ism
lític
qui
lí
ti
polí
socia
```

-- the actual code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use utf8;
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::Util qw(min);
use open ':encoding(utf8)';
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
binmode(STDIN, ":utf8");

generateProfile("es.txt", "ES"); #function call to read from file es.txt 
generateProfile("dt.txt", "DE"); #second call to read only from file dt.txt

sub generateProfile { 
    my $file= $_[0]; #taking arguments
    my $Lang = $_[1];

    open(IN, "<:utf8",$file) || die "error"; #to read file 
    open(OUT, ">:utf8", "profile$Lang.txt"); # to create and write in file e.g profileDe

    my (%ngramL); #any hash for later
    my $line; 
    my (@words);
    my (%ngramL);
    my (@uni, @bi, @tri, @quad, @five); #array which keeps letterkombinations of different length

    while($line =<IN>){ 
        chomp $line;
       # print $line;  # just for testing: during the second function call, it would print here old content from "es.txt" instead of only reading from "dt.txt"
        push(@words, $line);
        }
     close IN;   #doesn't it closed?

     foreach my $word (@words){
        bigramm($word); #split word in different letter combinations
        }

    freqL(); #fill that hash with frequences, how many times occures one letter combination e.g. "ab" = 2, "tion"=5
    print_hashL(); #print hash 

    sub bigramm{
      my $wort= $_[0];
      my $i; my $k;
      my @letters= split(//, $wort);
      for ($i=0; $i<length($wort)-0; $i++){ ####!!!!! -1?
        my $bi= substr($wort, $i, 1);
        push(@uni, $bi); }   
      for ($i=0; $i<length($wort)-1; $i++){
        my $bi= substr($wort, $i, 2);
        push(@bi, $bi); }
      for ($i=0; $i<length($wort)-2; $i++){
        my $bi= substr($wort, $i, 3);
        push(@tri, $bi); }
      for ($i=0; $i<length($wort)-3; $i++){
        my $bi= substr($wort, $i, 4);
        push(@quad, $bi); }
      for ($i=0; $i<length($wort)-4; $i++){
        my $bi= substr($wort, $i, 5);
        push(@five, $bi); }      

 }

    sub freqL{
      for my $duo (@uni, @bi, @tri, @quad, @five){
        if(defined $ngramL{$duo}) {$ngramL{$duo}++;}
        else {$ngramL{$duo}=1;}
    }
  }

    sub print_hashL{
      foreach my $elem(sort{$ngramL{$b}<=>$ngramL{$a}} keys %ngramL) {
        print OUT "$elem\n";}
     }

}
```

also there are some warnings, which may or may not cause this problem? :

```
"my" variable %ngramL masks earlier declaration in same scope at stack.pl line 23.
Variable "@uni" will not stay shared at stack.pl line 46.
Variable "@bi" will not stay shared at stack.pl line 49.
Variable "@tri" will not stay shared at stack.pl line 52.
Variable "@quad" will not stay shared at stack.pl line 55.
Variable "@five" will not stay shared at stack.pl line 58.
Variable "@uni" will not stay shared at stack.pl line 63.
Variable "@bi" will not stay shared at stack.pl line 63.
Variable "@tri" will not stay shared at stack.pl line 63.
Variable "@quad" will not stay shared at stack.pl line 63.
Variable "@five" will not stay shared at stack.pl line 63.
Variable "%ngramL" will not stay shared at stack.pl line 64.
Variable "%ngramL" will not stay shared at stack.pl line 70.
```

Comment: This part of the code looks ok. Does the `bigramm` sub use global variables or state variables? I would assume that bigramm caches (globally or in a state variable) its input and does not clear the cache afterwards.

Comment: I'm not an expert with subs inside subs, but if you declare `my (@words, %ngramL, @uni, @bi, @tri, @quad, @five)` outside any subs and reset then with `(@words, %ngramL, @uni, @bi, @tri, @quad, @five) = ();` when you call `generateProfile`, it will solve your problem. That's for the quick fix, I'll let someone with more experience/knowledge post a more precise answer. My guess is that the subs inside other subs are only compiled once, and the arrays/hashes that are declared outside of them but you use inside are turned into globales variables... but that's just a guess

Comment: i remodelled the whole code, there are no subs inside subs left, even tried packages and it's still behaving that way .. also the quick fix did work as long as i leave the code that way, but would i add just one other function call like generateProfile("en.txt", "EN"); it would mess up everything again ..

Answer (score 0):

```
while($line =<IN>){ 
    chomp $line;
    print $line;  # during the second function call, it would print here old content from "es.txt" instead of only reading from "dt.txt"
    push(@words, $line);
    close IN;   #doesn't it closed?
```

After you read one line from your input file, you basically close the filehandler. Then, when you go to the second line, you won't be able to read from file because you closed it before.

Comment: no i am sorry, this was a copy paste mistake .. i forgot to put a "}" there

Comment: How are you making the "call this funktion several times with different files" ? Code example?

Comment: here i meant by calling a function with different files these lines: 
(1) generateProfile("es.txt", "ES"); 
(2) generateProfile("dt.txt", "DE"); 
the paramters just change .. but after calling (1),  the stream in the second call seem to remember the first file and print lines from (1) and then (2)

Comment: Can you also add the content of the 2 files? I tested and I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/FLuaihT.png)
As you can see, there is no problem in your shown code

Comment: you are right, i just tried the code excerpt too, and it did work without problems .. i will edit my post again and will post more code .. because there is a problem